# Calling lwc method from aura read properties of undefined (then)

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I am calling lwc method from aura. It gives me error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')]. Here is my code. There were some complex logic, but it gives the same error with just returning true;

```
export default class LwcComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api lwcMethod() {
        return  true; //changed to "return Promise.resolve(true)";
    }
```

Aura

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init"
                  value="{!this}"
                  action="{!c.onInit}"
    />
    <c:LwcComponent  aura:id="lwcComponent"/>

</aura:component>

({
    onInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.doInit(component);
    }
})

({
    doInit: function (component) {

        component.find('lwcComponent').lwcMethod()
            .then($A.getCallback(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }));
    },
})
```

UPD:I debugged and it seems that method even is not called

Comment: It needs to return a `Promise` for `.then` to work.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried with promise.resolve and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_share_javascript

Also here are some communications patterns: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/inter-component-communication-patterns-for-lightning-web-components

I know these references are saying about data communication, but if we think a little, on javascript a function that could be passed through it,

Question:

1. Does your component.find('lwcComponent') is returning the element from the DOM?
2. Which event is not being called? the doInit?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2.lwcMethod. I added console.log and tin debud there are no entry at that point. But function is correct, because I tried with wrong one and there are another error. I will look into first link, thanks.